# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(\frac{\left(3^{1 / n}-1\right) \sqrt{2 n+1}}{\left(3^{1 / (n+1)}-1\right) \sqrt{2(n+1)}}-1\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to solve the following limit:
$\lim\limits _{n \to \infty} n\left(\frac{\left(3^{1 / n}-1\right) \sqrt{2 n+1}}{\left(3^{1 / (n+1)}-1\right) \sqrt{2(n+1)}}-1\right)$
where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

*Wolfram Mathematica* says the answer is $\frac{3}{4}$, but I don't know how to find it.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you know $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\operatorname{e}^{1/n}-1}{1/n}=1?$$

Comment: Wolfram doesn't say that for [your input](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit++n%28%28%283%5E%281%2Fn%29-1%29sqrt%282n%2B1%29%2F%28%283%5E%281%2Fn%2B1%29-1%29%28sqrt%282%28n%2B1%29%29%29%29%29-1%29). The way you wrote it, it clearly diverges to $-\infty$.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya Sorry, it turns out I've missed the parentheses for the power of 3 in the denominator, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using
$$ 3^x=1+x\ln3+\frac12x^2\ln^23+O(x^3),\sqrt{1-x}=1-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+O(x^3) $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim\limits _{n \to \infty} n\left(\frac{\left(3^{1 / n}-1\right) \sqrt{2 n+1}}{\left(3^{1 / (n+1)}-1\right) \sqrt{2(n+1)}}-1\right)\\
&=&\lim\limits _{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac1{n+1}}{3^{1 / (n+1)}-1}n(n+1)\frac{\left(3^{1 / n}-1\right) \sqrt{2 n+1}-\left(3^{1 / (n+1)}-1\right) \sqrt{2(n+1)}}{\sqrt{2(n+1)}}\\
&=&\lim\limits _{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln3}n(n+1)\bigg[\left(3^{1 / n}-1\right) \frac{\sqrt{2 n+1}}{{\sqrt{2(n+1)}}}-\left(3^{1 / (n+1)}-1\right)\bigg]\\
&=&\lim\limits _{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln3}n(n+1)\bigg[\left(3^{1 / n}-1\right) \sqrt{1-\frac1{2 n+2}}-\left(3^{1 / (n+1)}-1\right)\bigg]\\
&=&\lim\limits _{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln3}n(n+1)\bigg[\left(\frac{\ln3}{n}+\frac{\ln^23}{2n^2}+O(\frac1{n^3})\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{2(2n+2)}-\frac{1}{8(2n+2)^2}+O(\frac{1}{n^3})\right)\\
&&-\left(\frac{\ln3}{n+1}+\frac{\ln^23}{2(n+1)^2}+O(\frac1{n^3})\right)\bigg]\\
&=&\lim\limits _{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln3}n(n+1)\left(\frac{\ln3}{n}-\frac{\ln3}{n+1}+\frac{\ln^23}{2n^2}-\frac{\ln^23}{2(n+1)^2}-\frac{\ln3}{2n(2n+2)}+O(\frac1{n^3})\right)\\
&=&\lim\limits _{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln3}n(n+1)\left(\frac{3\ln3}{4n(n+1)}+\frac{(2n+1)\ln^23}{2n^2(n+1)^2}+O(\frac1{n^3})\right)\\
&=&\frac34.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: You are welcome.